# Java Swing - Passing an Event from child to parent without storing parent in child

Tags: java, swing, events

I'm making a game in Java Swing and I've come across an issue where I need to signal to my UI class `MainWindow` (that contains an instance of `GameLogic`) that the player has leveled up and that it needs to display the appropriate UI.

As I mentioned above MainWindow contains an instance of `GameLogic` and as its name implies it is responsible for updating and maintaining the game. When the player levels up I want to invoke an Event which the `MainWindow` can handle. How can I make this happen?

I want to avoid storing the MainWindow instance's reference in `GameLogic` as that could lead to problems when I'm deserializing a save using Gson. I tried simply having `GameLogic` extend ActionEvent, but I don't think that's a correct path to take as I'd need to call `ActionEvent`'s constructor within `GameLogic` as `super` but `ActionEvent` requires a non-null `source` which can't be `GameLogic` as it is being constructed so `this` isn't yet usable, but no other `Object` instance would make sense to be used there.

Another approach I thought of was just having an instance of `ActionEvent` within `GameLogic` but how would I set its actionListener to `MainWindow` without storing a reference for it?

At this point I realized that this was probably already done a lot, so it's better to resort to tried and tested solutions, so here I am. I'd appreciate general advice or links to sites where this specific issue is explored and solved/explained.

Comment: *As I mentioned above `MainWindow` contains an instance of `GameLogic`* So, when you create that instance, why not add `this` as an `ActionListener` to it?

Comment: I first need `GameLogic` to be an `ActionEvent` don't I?

Comment: Well no, you need to add `this` to be a listener for whatever *causes* the event in `GameLogic`. Let's say it's 'fooButton': `gameLogic.getFooButton().addActionListener(this);`

Comment: The `event` is the player killing an enemy which puts them over the cap for getting the next level, so not button or input-based

Comment: OK, but not hugely important. It's the pattern that counts. `Observer` \ `Observable` or custom event